# How to reduce PostgreSQL database size

Tags: postgresql

Here is my table structure

```
id
name varchar(150), 
timestamp_one bigint, 
timestamp_two bigint, 
value double, 
additional_list jsonb
```

I also have an index on these three fields:

```
name (varchar(150)), timestamp_one (bigint), additional_list (jsonb)
```

The database is quite fast with my queries and inserts. The problem I have that it is growing a lot. With the rate of data I have, it goes up to 100GB within a day. My main concert here is storage. What can I improve here? Can PostgreSQL compress my data? Will it be worth to create another table for name (varchar(150)) (it can be repeated for many rows) field and store foreign key, will it save a lot of data? Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Won't save space, but "timestamps" should be stored in a `timestamp` column, not as a number in a `bigint`. https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Comment: If name is repeated a lot, then yes, moving that to a separate table (where it's unique) might save space. But I would suspect the JSON column to take up the most space. You can check how much space each column takes using `select pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(name))), pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_column_size(list)))` from ...`

Comment: You have to find out if the table is bloated. If you can tolerate the down time, run `VACUUM (FULL)` on the table and see if it shrinks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I don't like timestamp fields b.c. they have time-zone, also it is easier for me to work with epoch timestamp stored in bigint field. is there any big difference with timestamp?

Comment: A `timestamp` does not use a time zone. A `timestamptz` (aka `timestamp with time zone`) does. But using time zones is a **good** thing, because otherwise you never know what point in time exactly a value refers to.  But I am impressed: I wouldn't know what real date the values `-47606400` or `1570027032` refer to